# How to keep the size of the Dalvik cache small?

Tags: cyanogenmod, internal-storage, dalvik

I have an issue with the Dalvik cache getting huge and occupying almost all of the space on my phone. I'm running Cyanogenmod 7.X. For the record, I have about 5-6 small applications on my phone (keyboard, voice choice, Gmail, etc.), but I'm showing about 187MB used and 9.7MB free on my internal storage in "Manage Applications".

I simple `du -h -d 1 /` reveals:

```
0   /sd-ext
0   /config
32.3M   /cache
0   /acct
3.5G    /mnt
120.8M  /system
0   /sys
112.0K  /sbin
0   /proc
178.3M  /data
0   /root
0   /dev
3.8G    /
```

Then, a `du -h -d 1 /data` reveals further:

```
550.5K  /data/tombstones
13.5K   /data/backup
10.5K   /data/dropbear
50.5K   /data/anr
4.0K    /data/secure
413.0K  /data/system
94.3M   /data/dalvik-cache
3.5K    /data/property
6.6M    /data/app
1.5M    /data/app-private
74.8M   /data/data
6.5K    /data/local
2.0K    /data/lost+found
46.5K   /data/misc
2.0K    /data/dontpanic
178.3M  /data
```

The "cache" is taking up 94.3MB of my internal phone storage?!? How does this make any sense? I did a cache wipe, but it was all regenerated on the next boot.

Another really weird but interesting thing is that if I do `du -h -d 1 /data/data`, I see that many of the apps I have moved to SD storage are still being stored on the phone!!!

```
34.5K   /data/data/com.google.android.carhome
31.0K   /data/data/com.paladinstudios.jimmypataya
33.0K   /data/data/com.touchtype.swiftkey
36.5K   /data/data/com.viber.voip
476.0K  /data/data/de.bigbyte.games.pickastick
21.5K   /data/data/com.android.keepass
50.5K   /data/data/com.threequbits.android.eightpen
12.5K   /data/data/com.google.android.apps.chrometophone
920.0K  /data/data/com.meganoid.engine
2.5K    /data/data/fishnoodle.jumpgate_free
2.5K    /data/data/com.androidemu.nes
48.5K   /data/data/digifit.virtuagym.client.android
49.5K   /data/data/com.rovio.angrybirdsseasons
641.0K  /data/data/com.googlecode.android_scripting
172.0K  /data/data/com.amazon.venezia
143.5K  /data/data/com.google.android.apps.docs
2.5K    /data/data/com.tumblr
26.5K   /data/data/de.android.telnet
5.0K    /data/data/com.capaci.android.flashlight
7.5K    /data/data/com.realarcade.DOJ
15.5K   /data/data/android.androidVNC
2.5K    /data/data/com.prey
12.0K   /data/data/org.mult.daap
13.0K   /data/data/org.transdroid
103.5K  /data/data/com.android.vending
30.5K   /data/data/com.google.android.talk
15.4M   /data/data/com.popcap.pvz
7.5K    /data/data/com.adobe.reader
29.0K   /data/data/gematria.calculator
4.0K    /data/data/com.android.setupwizard
161.5K  /data/data/com.glu.android.spacebros
4.0K    /data/data/com.google.android.onetimeinitializer
36.5K   /data/data/com.droidhen.game.donkeyjump
21.5K   /data/data/com.google.android.location
516.5K  /data/data/com.sherbert.delicious
9.5K    /data/data/com.google.android.voicesearch
4.0K    /data/data/com.google.android.apps.uploader
4.0K    /data/data/com.android.vending.updater
12.0K   /data/data/com.hg.gunsandgloryfree
4.0K    /data/data/com.google.android.latinimetutorial
198.0K  /data/data/com.google.android.gsf
11.0K   /data/data/com.google.android.street
5.0K    /data/data/com.bigtincan.android.adfree
73.5K   /data/data/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
176.0K  /data/data/com.bfs.ninjump
4.0K    /data/data/com.google.android.partnersetup
445.5K  /data/data/com.google.android.maps.mytracks
4.0K    /data/data/com.google.android.feedback
766.0K  /data/data/com.facebook.katana
9.5K    /data/data/com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts
9.5K    /data/data/com.google.android.syncadapters.calendar
7.0K    /data/data/pl.pawelbialecki.jedilightsaber
14.5K   /data/data/com.google.android.backup
127.0K  /data/data/com.google.android.apps.genie.geniewidget
2.0M    /data/data/com.shazam.encore.android
2.5K    /data/data/com.androidemu.gbc
4.0K    /data/data/com.android.cardock
1.2M    /data/data/com.rememberthemilk.MobileRTM
6.0K    /data/data/com.android.server.vpn
8.0K    /data/data/com.android.voicedialer
9.0K    /data/data/com.oktmwebsites.braslev
11.0K   /data/data/com.google.android.apps.tvremote
4.0K    /data/data/com.android.musicvis
423.5K  /data/data/com.google.android.apps.plus
7.5K    /data/data/com.tomanyz.lockWatch
15.0K   /data/data/com.android.providers.userdictionary
4.0K    /data/data/android.tts
2.5K    /data/data/Sidur.NosachSfarad.free
8.0K    /data/data/com.jyaif.pewpew
9.0K    /data/data/net.cactii.flash2
15.0K   /data/data/com.tmobile.thememanager
6.0K    /data/data/com.tmobile.themechooser
199.0K  /data/data/com.dropbox.android
233.5K  /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony
16.0K   /data/data/com.bbb.btr
5.0K    /data/data/org.nstamato.bansheeremote
6.5K    /data/data/com.android.systemui
2.5K    /data/data/com.adobe.flashplayer
38.5K   /data/data/com.noshufou.android.su
41.0K   /data/data/au.com.phil
744.5K  /data/data/de.hms.xconstructionfull
4.0K    /data/data/com.android.stk
2.5K    /data/data/com.lysolpionex.HomestarRunnerSoundboard
4.0K    /data/data/com.android.spare_parts
4.0K    /data/data/com.android.soundrecorder
2.5K    /data/data/com.androidemu.snes
48.0K   /data/data/com.android.providers.settings
204.5K  /data/data/com.android.settings
13.0K   /data/data/com.koushikdutta.rommanager
5.0K    /data/data/com.sec.ccl.csp.app.secretwallpaper.themetwo
6.5K    /data/data/com.voiceplusfree
7.0K    /data/data/com.nasc.widget.pixelartclock
4.0K    /data/data/com.android.protips
4.0K    /data/data/com.svox.pico
8.5K    /data/data/com.sportstracklive.stopwatch
2.9M    /data/data/com.google.android.apps.reader
14.5K   /data/data/com.android.phone
67.5K   /data/data/org.zwanoo.android.speedtest
5.5K    /data/data/com.replica.replicaisland
4.0K    /data/data/com.teamdouche.pacman
2.5K    /data/data/com.hg.gunsandglory
4.0K    /data/data/com.android.packageinstaller
42.0K   /data/data/com.squareup
7.0K    /data/data/com.android.music
12.0K   /data/data/com.android.mms
322.0K  /data/data/com.android.providers.media
34.5K   /data/data/org.adw.launcher
4.0K    /data/data/com.android.magicsmoke
4.0K    /data/data/com.android.wallpaper.livepicker
6.5K    /data/data/com.android.wallpaper
223.5K  /data/data/com.xyzmo.signature
33.5K   /data/data/com.a0soft.gphone.aCompass
18.0K   /data/data/com.android.inputmethod.latin
7.5K    /data/data/com.osao.themarbians
4.0K    /data/data/com.android.htmlviewer
320.0K  /data/data/org.onaips.vnc
2.7M    /data/data/com.cooliris.media
221.0K  /data/data/com.google.android.gm
4.0K    /data/data/org.openintents.filemanager
4.0K    /data/data/com.android.fm
7.5K    /data/data/com.publicobject.shush
47.0K   /data/data/com.android.email
4.0M    /data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid
44.5K   /data/data/org.droidstack
11.0K   /data/data/com.android.providers.drm
591.5K  /data/data/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup
1.2M    /data/data/com.google.android.apps.googlevoice
110.0K  /data/data/com.google.earth
4.0K    /data/data/com.android.providers.downloads.ui
40.5K   /data/data/com.android.providers.downloads
2.5K    /data/data/com.marvin.espeak
4.0M    /data/data/com.google.android.music
130.5K  /data/data/com.zeptolab.ctr
4.0K    /data/data/com.android.development
15.5K   /data/data/com.android.deskclock
4.0K    /data/data/com.android.defcontainer
21.0K   /data/data/com.miui.player
525.5K  /data/data/com.google.android.apps.books
4.0K    /data/data/com.bel.android.dspmanager
4.0K    /data/data/com.tmobile.theme.Cyanbread
1.5M    /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts
32.0K   /data/data/com.jawbone.companion
2.5K    /data/data/com.melodis.midomiMusicIdentifier
2.5K    /data/data/net.artifix.pomodroido.free
7.5K    /data/data/com.android.contacts
13.0K   /data/data/com.halfbrick.fruitninja
4.0K    /data/data/com.android.certinstaller
1.6M    /data/data/com.evernote
2.5K    /data/data/com.bw.picme.local
7.5K    /data/data/com.android.camera
417.5K  /data/data/com.android.providers.calendar
10.0K   /data/data/com.android.calendar
601.5K  /data/data/com.tencent.launcher
6.5K    /data/data/com.android.calculator2
4.0K    /data/data/com.cyanogenmod.CMWallpapers
7.0K    /data/data/com.cyanogenmod.updatenotify
570.0K  /data/data/com.google.android.apps.maps
2.0M    /data/data/com.subatomicstudios
9.0K    /data/data/com.cyanogenmod.stats
29.5K   /data/data/com.t4ils.tapandcrash
2.5K    /data/data/com.androidemu.gens
11.0K   /data/data/com.cyanogenmod.cmparts
7.9M    /data/data/com.android.browser
6.5K    /data/data/DoodleLander.DoodleLander
722.0K  /data/data/ca.jamdat.flight.scrabblefree
13.5K   /data/data/com.android.bluetooth
31.0K   /data/data/com.androidemu.gba
243.5K  /data/data/com.popcap.peggle
4.0K    /data/data/com.android.providers.applications
4.0K    /data/data/com.tmobile.theme.Androidian
4.0K    /data/data/jackpal.androidterm2
2.5K    /data/data/gabriel.metronome
6.0K    /data/data/com.android.providers.subscribedfeeds
25.0K   /data/data/com.tuneme.tuneme
16.5K   /data/data/com.android.launcher
12.1M   /data/data/com.swype.android.installer
7.5K    /data/data/inediblesoftware.shotgun
61.5K   /data/data/com.silvertree.cordy
36.5K   /data/data/com.pandora.android
45.5K   /data/data/com.google.android.youtube
44.0K   /data/data/com.google.android.stardroid
2.5K    /data/data/org.wordpress.android
70.0K   /data/data/com.mint
1.4M    /data/data/com.netflix.mediaclient
56.5K   /data/data/com.rovio.angrybirdsrio
267.5K  /data/data/com.rovio.angrybirds
13.0K   /data/data/com.google.android.apps.translate
2.5K    /data/data/org.transdroid.search
421.5K  /data/data/com.twitter.android
171.5K  /data/data/com.google.android.apps.unveil
543.5K  /data/data/com.swype.android.inputmethod
11.0K   /data/data/com.storybird.spacebusterlite
17.0K   /data/data/com.gindin.zmanim.android
8.5K    /data/data/com.dikkar.irecord
22.5K   /data/data/com.gotow.hexdefense
46.5K   /data/data/com.mybo.tetris
74.8M   /data/data
```

In short, I have no idea what's going on, but I've ensured that almost no applications are living on my internal storage and I'm *still* getting "Phone Memory Low" in the notification bar. What gives?

Comment: See also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60534/wiping-dalvik-cache-dalvik-cache-of-uninstalled-apps

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`/data/dalvik-cache` contains optimized bytecode of each installed app.  `/data/data` contains settings and preferences of each installed app.  Neither of these two locations are touched when you move the app to SD Card using Gingerbread's built-in methods.  That's a limitation of Android's implementation of moving apps to SD.  CyanogenMod 7 allows you to move more apps than the stock ROM, but on phones with limited storage you will still eventually run out of space on internal memory.

Since you are rooted and already running CM7, take a look at [S2E](https://market.android.com/details?id=ru.krikun.s2e).  This app allows you to move both `/data/data` and `data/dalvik-cache` to your SD Card.  The only prerequisite is that your SD Card must be re-partitioned to add a second Ext2/3/4 partition, after the main FAT32 one.  There are many partition tools available (free and paid) that can do this for you.  I personally use [PartitionWizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/)'s [MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) (Windows, freeware).  It is also recommended to use a stand-alone USB SD Card reader for repartitioning as opposed to built-in readers on most laptops, since those tend to not properly write partition tables to SD Cards.

P.S. Don't forget to back up the contents of the SD Card before attempting to re-partition it, since it will wipe all of your data from it.

Comment: Now if I can only find a way to free up enough space on my phone to install the app...

Comment: Uninstall Angry Birds!  ;)

Comment: Touché. Now, if only I would have backed up my SD card before I partitioned it. I hear the sound of a wasted day whizzing by...

Comment: Ouch.  I didn't think to include that bit in my answer.  Better edit it and add that.

Comment: All things considered, is this really an improvement? You might have freed up some RAM, but won't apps run slower since even the "optimized cache" is stored on the SD card?

Comment: @briankb depending on the rating of your SD Card, there is definitely a trade-off here.  Yes, you might notice that apps start a bit slower than usual.  Once they are in memory though, there would be no difference in speed while they are running.  On the flip side - you can install a much greater number of apps without running out if internal storage.

Comment: I think you should strongly consider using Link2SD from the Android Market. That should help you with a lot of this!