# Wiping dalvik cache - Dalvik cache of uninstalled apps

Tags: applications, insufficient-memory, uninstallation, cache, dalvik

I just came across the folder `dalvik-cache` having size of about 750MB.

I searched for dalvik cache on google, and came to know that it is builded during boot up, and wiping this will make the next boot slower.

So whether wiping dalvik cache is not at all useful?

My doubt is that whether Dalvik cache has some files related to only the uninstalled apps?

If so, how we can find that files?

Or Dalvik cache components get deleted when we uninstall an app?

***EDIT**: My phone is rooted.*

Comment: If you are rooted there is an option in Titanium Backup Pro to remove anything from the Dalvik Cache not linked to an app. This orphan data suggests that data may remain in the cache after the app is no longer using it or even uninstalled.

Comment: Ok.. @RossC .. Please add this as **answer** (with some more details on this unused/junk `dalvik cache`, and how to wipe this using `Titanium backup`) Thanks... _EDIT: Yes, my phone is rooted._

Comment: There's also nothing wrong with periodically wiping your device's Dalvik cache using a custom recover like TWRP. It might take a little bit longer to start up some apps, but that would be almost unnoticeable on most modern devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @[RossC](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/40036/rossc) and @[filoxo](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/37474/filoxo) for your comments.

Adding these as answer:

> If you are rooted there is an option in [Titanium Backup Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro) to remove
>   anything from the Dalvik Cache not linked to an app. This orphan data
>   suggests that data may remain in the cache after the app is no longer
>   using it or even uninstalled.
>
> There's also nothing wrong with periodically wiping your device's
>   Dalvik cache using a custom recover like [TWRP](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=TWRP&rlz=1C1WSCA_enIN572IN572&oq=TWRP&aqs=chrome..69i57.191j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=TWRP). It might take a little
>   bit longer to start up some apps, but that would be almost
>   unnoticeable on most modern devices.